# How to iterate through json variable in AWS Lambda Template Mapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How can I iterate through the entire $input.json('$') object in AWS lambda mapping template?

I tried this but it doesn't seem to return anything.

```
#set($inputJson = $util.escapeJavaScript($input.json('$')))
{
  #foreach($entry in $inputJson.keySet())
  "$type" : $inputJson.get($entry)
  #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
  #end
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you talking about API gateway mapping templates? Lambda does not have such a feature.

Comment: @luk2302 Yes API gateway mapping templates. Thanks for letting me know, is there a possible workaround?